# *ngFor using item.string instead item.fieldName in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a problem.

```
<tr class="info" *ngFor="let item of test">
<td>{{item.field1}} </td>
```

This is normal using.
I have a variable, its name FieldName. And it has a string value 'field1'.

Can i use like this? Is it possible?

```
<td> {{item. (FieldName's Value)}} </td>
```

Comment: try using `{{item[FieldName]}}`

Comment: it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
<td>{{item[FieldName]}} </td>
```

Comment: But I need array's variable. It will just write 'field1'.

Comment: <td>{{item[FieldName]}} </td>

Comment: Can i use this way for 'List' type? I'm trying it and which doesn't recognize list's properties like 'push'. @Sajeetharan